Normals deformation with FFD
I am developing an FFD tool in Unity for the needs of a level designer. It works similarly to FFD box in 3DS Max. I used the implementation described by Sederberg and Parry with a lattice and Bernstein polynomials to calculate the weights of the control points.
I succeeded in implementing vertex deformation, but I haven't figured out what to do with the normals. The most obvious solution is to recalculate them after each deformation. However, the models that will be used with this tool in the game have custom normals configured in 3DS Max. If I recalculate them from scratch, they will be lost.
Therefore, I am looking for a solution that can be used to adjust the original vertex normals after deforming the vertices. I can't use transformation matrices because FFD only displaces points, but the normals need to be rotated, and FFD is a non-linear transformation.
Question:
Is it possible to adjust the original normals (not recalculate from zero) knowing the original and deformed vertex positions? If yes, how can this be done?
I'm using this formula for deformation:
$$x_{ffd}=
\sum_{i=0}^l 
\begin{pmatrix}
l \\
i \\
\end{pmatrix}
(1-s)^{l-i}s^i
[ \sum_{j=0}^m
\begin{pmatrix}
m \\
j \\
\end{pmatrix}
(1-t)^{m-j}t^j
[ \sum_{k=0}^n
\begin{pmatrix}
n \\
k \\
\end{pmatrix}
(1-u)^{n-k}u^kP_{ijk}]]
$$
And here's my code for the vertex deformation method:
    /// <summary>
    /// Deforms a single vertex based on the given lattice.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="vertex">The vertex to deform (in bezier space).</param>
    /// <param name="lattice">The lattice used for deformation.</param>
    /// <param name="deformedVertex">The resulting deformed vertex.</param>
    public void Deform(in Vector3 vertex, in Lattice lattice, out Vector3 deformedVertex)
    {
        deformedVertex = Vector3.zero;

        for (var index = 0; index < lattice.Points.Length; index++)
        {
            Vector3 point = lattice.Points[index];
            Vector3Int pointIndex = lattice.Indices[index];
    
            var bX = Bernstein(vertex.x, pointIndex.x, lattice.Size.x - 1, _combinationsX);
            var bY = Bernstein(vertex.y, pointIndex.y, lattice.Size.y - 1, _combinationsY);
            var bZ = Bernstein(vertex.z, pointIndex.z, lattice.Size.z - 1, _combinationsZ);
    
            deformedVertex += point * (bX * bY * bZ);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the Bernstein polynomial value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="t">The parameter value.</param>
    /// <param name="i">The index of the polynomial term.</param>
    /// <param name="n">The degree of the polynomial.</param>
    /// <param name="combinations">The precomputed combination values.</param>
    /// <returns>The value of the Bernstein polynomial.</returns>
    private float Bernstein(float t, int i, int n, float[] combinations)
    {
        return combinations[i] * Mathf.Pow(t, i) * Mathf.Pow(1 - t, n - i);
    }


This should be a matter of computing the partial derivatives of the FFD displacement function with regard to x, y, and z. This will give you a set of three vectors representing the direction/speed the point should move if its x/y/z were displaced infinitesimally in those directions. You can use these as the columns of a matrix & multiply the normal by its inverse transpose to transform it into this distorted neighbourhood relative to the displaced point, then rescale its length. Want to share the formulas or code you're using, so I or another user can demonstrate how to do this in more detail?

Thank you for the comment, @DMGregory. I've added the formula and code to my question.
You wrote about the Jacobian matrix, right?
I'm not good at math, so I have no idea how I can calculate partial derivatives for this function.

I converted the math formula from an image into MathJax markdown, but the image quality wasn't the best and I may have misread something. Please double check that formula and edit or comment as needed.
